# Excel: How to split Column Value under Particular column Name

Tags: microsoft-excel, macros

I have the Main Value as per below table. Now, I need to keep the each value under particular column name .All the values are space separated. Let say, the Main value is:2 3 6 7.

Now, 2 should goes under the column name 2. 3 Should goes under the column name 3 and same as 6 should goes under the column name 6 and 7 should goes under the column name 7. In excel there have a option name "text to column". Using this function the value can split but it's not goes to it's  particular column name.

[image]

Please help , how shall I do that. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? This seems something that can be easily done in Power Query (available in Excel 2010+ and Microsoft 365) or VBA. Probably also could be done with some of the advanced Excel functions.

Comment: Why have you posted here as well? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76141068/how-to-split-column-value-under-particular-column-name/76141258#76141258

Answer (score 1):

Check if this works for you.

[image]

Sample data as shown in above screenshot.

Formula in D6

```
=IF(SUM(IF(D$4=TRANSPOSE((FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM($C6)," ","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s"))),1,0))>=1,D$4,"")
```

Drag it along across the table cells.

In older versions of Excel prior to 2021 and O365 you may need to press CTRL + SHIFT + ENTER from within the formula bar to create an Array Formula.